# How do I get the MSRP (manufactures suggested retail price) using Amazon MWS API C#?

Tags: c#, amazon-mws

I can get most of the Product details using the [MWS API](https://developer.amazonservices.com/gp/mws/docs.html) except the amazon suggested retail price (The amount crossed out on most products on top of the offer price).

ChannelMax has a way of getting it somehow - if not through the MWS API maybe they're crawling? The Documentation does not seem to mention it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that by "The amount crossed out at most products on top of the actual box price" you mean the Manufacturer Suggested Retail Price (`<MSRP>`), which is documented in the [XML Documentation](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/02/rainier/help/XML_Documentation_Intl._V158772716_.pdf)

[GetMatchingProduct](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/products/Products_GetMatchingProduct.html) seems to return a `<ListPrice>`. I haven't tried, but it might be the same as MSRP.

Comment: Does that work for retrieving the information or only for posting it in `CreateProduct` feeds?

Comment: @Hazzit I need it as a lookup, Is there a way to get it using the MWS API without feeds?

Comment: `GetMatchingProduct` seems to return a `<ListPrice>`. I haven't tried, but it might be the same as MSRP. http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/products/Products_GetMatchingProduct.html

Comment: @Hazzit Thanks so much that seems to be it!, I didn't realize that it's one of the Item Attributes inside one of the response elements, (I thought the response elements in the API docs are all that are returned, should have checked the XML response).
Edit your answer with your comment above and I'll mark it answered!.